# Customizar Asp.net Identity - Várias classes como User no Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

Sabemos que nosso usuário no asp.net identity é a classe com nome de `ApplicationUser`
Gostaria de criar outras classes que herdem dela
Por que?
Por que, digamos que eu tenha a classe Cliente, Vendedor, Usuário.

Quero que todos eles sejam usuários do meu sistema

Então tenho a minha classe padrão que vem ao criar o projeto:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

E tenho minha classe cliente por exemplo.

```
public class Cliente: ApplicationUser
{
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
}
```

Ao ir para a action Register, passei o Cliente para registrar como usuário, já que o mesmo herda de ApplicationUser:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(Cliente model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { 
            UserName = model.UserName,
        };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.PasswordHash);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Ao ir para essa Action, me deparo com o seguinte erro:

```
Invalid column name 'CNPJ'.
```

Ao tentar chamar o método `CreateAsync(user,model.PasswordHash)`

O que estou fazendo errado? Posso fazer isso que estou fazendo? Herdar e ter várias classes como "user" no identity?

PS: Já fiz migrations e dei update-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duas maneiras de resolver:

### 1. Faça Cliente herdar direto de IdentityUser

```
public class Cliente : IdentityUser
{
     [CNPJ]
     public string CNPJ { get; set; }
}
```

### 2. Coloque CNPJ direto em ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     [CNPJ]
     public string CNPJ { get; set; }
}
```

Aproveitando, vou te passar meu `CNPJAttribute` para validação:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class CNPJ : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        int[] multiplicador1 = new int[12] { 5, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        int[] multiplicador2 = new int[13] { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };

        int soma, resto;

        string digito, tempCnpj, CNPJ;

        CNPJ = value.ToString().Trim();
        CNPJ = CNPJ.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "").Replace("/", "");

        if (CNPJ.Length != 14)
            return new ValidationResult("CNPJ Inválido.");

        tempCnpj = CNPJ.Substring(0, 12);
        soma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            soma += int.Parse(tempCnpj[i].ToString()) * multiplicador1[i];
        resto = (soma % 11);

        if (resto < 2)
            resto = 0;
        else
            resto = 11 - resto;

        digito = resto.ToString();
        tempCnpj = tempCnpj + digito;
        soma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
            soma += int.Parse(tempCnpj[i].ToString()) * multiplicador2[i];
        resto = (soma % 11);

        if (resto < 2)
            resto = 0;
        else
            resto = 11 - resto;

        digito = digito + resto.ToString();

        if (CNPJ.EndsWith(digito))
            return null;
        else
            return new ValidationResult("CNPJ Inválido.");
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nunca tentei algo assim com tantas camadas de herança. Normalmente deixo minhas aplicações a níveis de estratificação simplificados. De repente posso tentar alguma coisa.