# Fazer mais de uma condição annotation asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho minha classe

e nela tenho uma propriedade

```
public TipoPessoa TipoPessoa {get;set;}
```

A mesma é um enumerador que tem valor "Fisica e Juridica"

E tenho uma propriedade que é CNPJ OU CPF

```
public string Cpf_Cnpj {get;set;}
```

Como eu faço para ele fazer a condição na hora de validar na anotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando um atributo misto de validação. [Em outra resposta, ensinei como implementar um atributo que valida CNPJs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16650/customizar-asp-net-identity-v%C3%A1rias-classes-como-user-no-identity/16652#16652). O desafio é fazer a mesma validação para o CPF.

Não estou com o código do CPF agora, mas vou editar a questão mais tarde colocando um exemplo de atributo para validação de CPF.