# Sugestão Migração Sistema e modelagem de pessoas físicas e jurídicas em sistema com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Bom, a questão é o seguinte. Tenho um banco de dados que tem a finalidade de fazer o livro caixa de uma empresa, basicamente esse banco tem uma tabela `CaixaCorrido` com as colunas `Id`, `PessoaNome`, `DataHora`, `Descricao`, `Valor`, `Tipo` (Entrada ou saída).

Surgiu então a necessidade de detalhar mais esse sistema, como por exemplo ter um cadastro de `pessoa`, podendo ser `física` ou `jurídica`, porém no sistema antigo isso não era informado.

Então gostaria de sugestões de como realizar essa migração dos dados, sendo que estou usando `c#`, com `EntityFramework`, `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica` herdam de `Pessoa`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primeiro vamos analisar se a derivação de `Pessoa` é uma composição ou uma herança. Como uma `Pessoa` não pode ser física e jurídica ao mesmo tempo, então é um caso de **herança** (uma tabela representa as duas entidades). Se pudesse, seria um caso de **composição** (uma tabela comum + 2 tabelas representando o complemento de dados de cada entidade).

Assim sendo, uma boa modelagem seria o seguinte:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String NomeOuRazaoSocial { get; set; }
}

public class PessoaFisica : Pessoa
{
    [Required]
    [Cpf] // Mais abaixo coloco a implementação desse atributo.
    [Unico(ErrorMessage = "Já existe uma pessoa física com este CPF.", ModelType = typeof(PessoaFisica))] // Deste também.
    public String Cpf { get; set; }
}

public class PessoaJuridica : Pessoa
{
    [Required]
    [Cnpj] // Mais abaixo coloco a implementação desse atributo.
    [Unico(ErrorMessage = "Já existe uma pessoa jurídica com este CNPJ.", ModelType = typeof(PessoaJuridica))] // Deste também.
    public String Cnpj { get; set; }
}
```

[Aqui tem `[Cnpj]`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16650/customizar-asp-net-identity-v%C3%A1rias-classes-como-user-no-identity/16652#16652).

[Aqui tem `[Cpf]`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100327/inputmask-pelo-model/100331#100331).

## `UnicoAttribute.cs`

Antes de implementar este atributo, [instale o pacote System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class UnicoAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public Type ModelType { get; set; }

    public UnicoAttribute() : base() { }
    public UnicoAttribute(Type _modelType) : base()
    {
        ModelType = _modelType;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        using (MeuContext db = new MeuContext())
        {
            var Name = validationContext.MemberName;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            {
                var displayName = validationContext.DisplayName;
                var prop = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(displayName);

                if (prop != null)
                {
                    Name = prop.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    var props = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.CustomAttributes.Count(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(DisplayAttribute)) > 0).ToList();

                    foreach (PropertyInfo prp in props)
                    {
                        var attr = prp.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.AttributeType == typeof(DisplayAttribute));

                        var val = attr.NamedArguments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MemberName == "Name").TypedValue.Value;

                        if (val.Equals(displayName))
                        {
                            Name = prp.Name;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            PropertyInfo IdProp = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomAttributes.Count(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(KeyAttribute)) > 0);

            var Id = (Guid)IdProp.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            Type entityType = validationContext.ObjectType;

            var result = db.Set(ModelType ?? entityType).Where(Name + "==@0", value);
            int count = 0;

            if (Id != Guid.Empty)
            {
                result = result.Where(IdProp.Name + "<>@0", Id);
            }

            count = result.Count();

            if (count == 0)
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            else
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString);
        }
    }
}
```

Para migrar os dados, você pode montar um script SQL com a tabela já criada por *Migrations* ou fazer um *Seed*. *Seed* é recomendado para pequenos volumes de dados. O script SQL para volumes grandes.

Se o caminho for pelo script SQL, atente-se para o preenchimento da coluna `discriminator` com "PessoaFisica" ou "PessoaJuridica".

Comment: Mas Cigano, como vou saber se a pessoa do meu outro sistema é física ou jurídica? Estava pensando em criar um tipo de pessoa `Outra` e armazenar essas pessoas desse sistema nessa entidade, e com o tempo ir atualizando esses cadastros e transformando elas em Física ou Jurídica

Comment: É uma boa ideia, mas a conversão de "Outra" para outro tipo de pessoa não pode ser feita pelo EF. Você vai ter que fazer um comando manual atualizando o Discriminator.

Comment: Tinha pensando em algo tipo unificar os cadastros, tipo se tiver as pessoas do tipo outra: Pablo, Pablo Vargas, Pablo de Vargas então criaria um cadastro de pessoa física Pablo Tondolo de Vargas e unificaria os cadastros do tipo outras. e impediria de usar os cadastros do tipo outra

Comment: Então acho que você teria que partir pra composição, e não herança. Se quiser, escrevo mais uma resposta.

Comment: Ta tranquilho Cigano, a minha duvida mesmo não é como fazer a nível de programação. Vou manter herança mesmo e criar mais uma entidade herdando de pessoa e largar tudo lá como se fosse um tipo de temporário.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, quanto a validação de campos únicos no Banco de Dados, não seria melhor fazer isto no [`DbContext.ValidateEntity`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/validate-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx)?

Comment: @TobiasMesquita Essa resposta é meio antiga. Se quiser fazer a versão do `ValidateEntity`, agradeceremos!

Answer (score 3):

Complementando a resposta do Cigano, validações que precisam consultar o Banco de Dados, podem ser feitas direto no Contexto, para tal para sobrescrever o método [`DbContext.ValidateEntity`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/validate-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx)

> Antes de implementar este atributo, [instale o pacote
>   System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/):

```
public class IndexAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute
{
    public string ErrorMessageString { get; set; }
}

protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
{
    var result = base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
    var entidade = entityEntry.Entity;
    var dataSet = this.Set(entidade.GetType());
    var propriedades = entidade.GetType()
        .GetProperties();

    var keysProps = propriedades
        .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false).Any())
        .ToList();

    var indices = propriedades
        .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IndexAttribute), false).Any())
        .Select(x => new { PropertyInfo = x, Indice = (IndexAttribute)x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IndexAttribute), false).First() })
        .Where(x => x.Indice.IsUnique)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Indice.Name, x => x)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());

    var indiceNames = new string[indices.Count];
    indices.Keys.CopyTo(indiceNames, 0);
    foreach (var indiceName in indiceNames)
    {
        var indiceProps = indices[indiceName];
        var consulta = dataSet.AsQueryable();
        foreach (var indiceProp in indiceProps.Select(x => x.PropertyInfo))
        {
            var indice = indiceProp.GetValue(entidade, null);
            consulta = consulta.Where(indiceProp.Name + "==@0", indice);
        }
        foreach (var keyProp in keysProps)
        {
            var key = keyProp.GetValue(entidade, null);
            consulta = consulta.Where(keyProp.Name + "<>@0", key);
        }

        var resultado = consulta.ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (resultado.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var link in indiceProps)
            {
                result.ValidationErrors.Add(new DbValidationError(link.PropertyInfo.Name, link.Indice.ErrorMessageString));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**P.S.: Tentei adaptar o código escrito pelo cigano, porém não testei o mesmo.**

Comment: Faltou dizer que tem que instalar o System.Linq.Dynamic.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez feito.