# Modelagem de herança MySQL e C#

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, herança

Estou com uma dúvida quanto a modelagem de um sistema DesktopApplication em C# com MySQL.

Essencialmente terei as entidades Cliente, Fornecedor, PF e PJ.
PF pode ser um cliente ou fornecedor. E PJ também pode ser um cliente ou fornecedor. Meu objetivo é utilizar Entity Framework e minha maior preocupação é com o desempenho nas consultas, listagens de registros e relatórios.
Vi várias abordagens e discussões a respeito, mas nada conclusiva.

Enfim, estou em dúvida entre as 3 opções de modelagem a seguir:

Opção 1:

```
CLIENTE
-id_cliente

FORNECEDOR
-id_fornecedor

PF
-id_pf
-id_cliente (não obrigatório)
-id_fornecedor (não obrigatório)

PJ
-id_pj
-id_cliente (não obrigatório)
-id_fornecedor (não obrigatório)
```

Opção 2:

```
CLIENTE
-id_cliente
-id_pj (não obrigatório)
-id_pf (não obrigatório)

FORNECEDOR
-id_fornecedor
-id_pj (não obrigatório)
-id_pf (não obrigatório)

PF
-id_pf

PJ
-id_pj
```

Opção 3 (que eu costumava usar):

```
CLIENTE
-id_cliente
-id_pessoa (obrigatório)
-tipo (para indicar se o id_pessoa é na tabela PF ou PJ)

FORNECEDOR
-id_fornecedor
-id_pessoa (obrigatório)
-tipo (para indicar se o id_pessoa é na tabela PF ou PJ)

PF
-id_pf

PJ
-id_pj
```

Não sei como ficaria o modelo em C# nesta 3ª opção. Sei que a nível apenas de banco, seria mais eficiente, mas como ficariam os modelos no C#? Acho que ele não entenderia esta forma.

Alguém poderia dar uma orientação para resolução deste impasse? Se puder dar exemplos de implementação de consultas para a melhor sugestão eu serei imensamente grato!

---

Baseado nas excelentes respostas que vocês me deram, montei o modelo da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao gerar os modelos ficaram desta forma:

```
[Table("pessoa")]
public partial class pessoa
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public pessoa()
    {
        cliente = new HashSet<cliente>();
        fornecedor = new HashSet<fornecedor>();
        pessoafisica = new HashSet<pessoafisica>();
        pessoajuridica = new HashSet<pessoajuridica>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int idPessoa { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(90)]
    public string nomeRazaoSocial { get; set; }

    public bool pf { get; set; }

}



[Table("pessoafisica")]
public partial class pessoafisica
{
    [Key]
    public int idPessoaFisica { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string cpf { get; set; }

    public int idPessoa { get; set; }

    public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }
}


[Table("pessoajuridica")]
public partial class pessoajuridica
{
    [Key]
    public int idPessoaJuridica { get; set; }

    [StringLength(45)]
    public string cnpj { get; set; }

    public int idPessoa { get; set; }

    public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

Ou seja, não ficou uma especialização a nível de código.

Falando em termos práticos! Se eu quiser montar uma listagem de todas as pessoas, com as colunas id_pessoa, nomeOuRazaoSocial, CPF/CNPJ.

Neste caso eu teria que usar if else para saber se é PF ou PJ e saber se eu busco a informação no objeto pessoafisica ou pessoajuridica?

Existe alguma estratégia no Entity para que o objeto pessoa saiba de onde ele deve pegar essa informação?

Qual seria a solução de alto nível para essa questão?

Mais uma vez agradeço!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Nesta resposta, explico como fazer herança para Pessoas Físicas e Jurídicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117219/sugest%C3%A3o-migra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-sistema/117243#117243).

Tendo isso, `Cliente` e `Fornecedor` seriam **composições** de uma `Pessoa`. Veja que na resposta citada eu falo sobre herança e composição. Assim sendo, os *Models* ficariam da seguinte forma:

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Pessoa")]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    // Coloque os demais campos aqui.

    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}

public class Fornecedor
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Pessoa")]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    // Coloque os demais campos aqui.

    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

`Pessoa` receberia mais duas propriedades de navegação:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String NomeOuRazaoSocial { get; set; }

    // As duas propriedades de navegação vão aqui
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public virtual Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
}
```

Ou seja, uma `Pessoa` pode ser um `Cliente`, um `Fornecedor`, ambos ou nenhum.

---

Sua modelagem está ok, mas precisa de alguns ajustes, sobretudo porque você omitiu uma das melhores funcionalidades do Entity Framework, que é justamente a especialização a nível de código:

```
[Table("pessoa")]
// Não há motivo para usar partial classes em Models. 
// Você pode retirar a declaração.
public class pessoa
{
    // Construtores **nunca** devem ser usados para inicializar 
    // propriedades de navegação, então estou comentando.
    /* [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public pessoa()
    {
        cliente = new HashSet<cliente>();
        fornecedor = new HashSet<fornecedor>();
        pessoafisica = new HashSet<pessoafisica>();
        pessoajuridica = new HashSet<pessoajuridica>();
    } */

    [Key]
    public int idPessoa { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(90)]
    public string nomeRazaoSocial { get; set; }

    // Essa propriedade não precisa.
    // public bool pf { get; set; }
}


[Table("pessoafisica")]
public class pessoafisica : pessoa
{
    // A chave já está em pessoa, então não precisa estar aqui.
    // [Key]
    // public int idPessoaFisica { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string cpf { get; set; }

    // Mesma coisa do comentário anterior.
    // public int idPessoa { get; set; }
    // public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }
}


[Table("pessoajuridica")]
public class pessoajuridica : pessoa
{
    // Idem
    // [Key]
    // public int idPessoaJuridica { get; set; }

    [StringLength(45)]
    public string cnpj { get; set; }

    // Idem
    // public int idPessoa { get; set; }    
    // public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

> Se eu quiser montar uma listagem de todas as pessoas, com as colunas id_pessoa, nomeOuRazaoSocial, CPF/CNPJ.

Todas as pessoas:

```
var pessoas = db.Pessoas.ToList(); // Sem CPF/CNPJ
```

Todas as pessoas com CPF e CNPJ:

```
var pessoas = db.PessoasFisicas
                .Select(pf => new { 
                              NomeOuRazaoSocial = pf.nomeRazaoSocial, 
                              CpfCnpj = pf.cpf
                       })
                .ToList()
                .Concat(db.PessoasJuridicas
                          .Select(pj => new { 
                             NomeOuRazaoSocial = pj.nomeRazaoSocial,
                             CpfCnpj = pj.cnpj
                          })
                          .ToList());
```

Usando um *ViewModel*:

```
var pessoas = db.PessoasFisicas
                .Select(pf => new PessoaViewModel { 
                              NomeOuRazaoSocial = pf.nomeRazaoSocial, 
                              CpfCnpj = pf.cpf
                       })
                .ToList()
                .Concat(db.PessoasJuridicas
                          .Select(pj => new PessoaViewModel { 
                             NomeOuRazaoSocial = pj.nomeRazaoSocial,
                             CpfCnpj = pj.cnpj
                          })
                          .ToList());
```

> Neste caso eu teria que usar if else para saber se é PF ou PJ e saber se eu busco a informação no objeto pessoafisica ou pessoajuridica?

Não precisa nada disso. Apenas mapear 3 contextos e selecionar por cada um deles:

```
public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
public DbSet<PessoaFisica> PessoasFisicas { get; set; }
public DbSet<PessoaJuridica> PessoasJuridicas { get; set; }
```

> Existe alguma estratégia no Entity para que o objeto pessoa saiba de onde ele deve pegar essa informação?

Checando o objeto:

```
var pessoa = db.Pessoas.First(p => p.Id == 1);
if (pessoa is PessoaFisica) { /* Faça alguma coisa */ }
if (pessoa is PessoaJuridica) { /* Faça outra coisa */ }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação, Cigano... Mas não consegui mapear os modelos do banco de dados da forma que você sugeriu... eu editei a pergunta com mais informações! Agradeço muito por qualquer conhecimento que possa compartilhar... Abraços!

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Veja se te atende.

Comment: Cigano, fantástico! Eu realmente estava complicando algo que é muito mais simples! Já fiz vários testes usando suas considerações e fiquei impressionado como ficou funcional, limpo e inteligível o código. Posso pedir uma última ajuda? A View que vai receber a lista de todas as pessoas (físicas ou jurídicas) deve receber que modelo para funcionar? Por default ela ficou como 
@model IEnumerable<Pessoa>, mas aí não funciona porque a lista que estou mandando tem o campo CpfCnpj que não tem no modelo pessoa. Pensei em criar uma model só para a view, mas mesmo assim não deu certo. Que faço? Brigadão

Comment: Crie um `PessoaViewModel`. Ao invés de fazer `.Select(pf => new { ...`, use: `.Select(pf => new PessoaViewModel { ...`. Aí você consegue tipar a *View* com `@model IEnumerable<PessoaViewModel>`

Comment: Ah... agora consegui! Valeu mesmo, Cigano! Nota 1000!

Comment: Editei de novo. Veja que alterei o exemplo.

Comment: Cigano, empatei em outra questão... se puder me ajudar está em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117567/herança-x-composição-mysql-c-entity 
Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Eu resolvi isto criando uma tabela de Pessoas
Pessoas tem um campo Tipo [Fisica, Juridica]

Um Cliente, aponta para uma Pessoa
Um Funcionário, aponta para uma pessoa
etc ...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Do modo como estou desenvolvendo,
uma PESSOA pode ser CLIENTE, VENDEDOR, FUNCIONÁRIO, tanto fisica quanto juridica :-)

Comment: A ideia é usar Entity Framework. Como ficaria isso no Entity Framework?

Comment: ué, eu estou usando Entity Framework, isto é para um aplicativo Win32

Comment: Mas pode perfeitamente ser usado para ASP, não vejo problemas. Inclusive uso uma UnitOfWork, que  faz o acesso aos dados ser transparente para a camada visual que você escolher, Web, Mobile, OS

Comment: Obrigado, duardbr! Eu concordo absolutamente com o modelo que você sugeriu! Minha dúvida está mais nos modelos do sistema... eu completei a pergunta com mais informações! Agradeço bastante por qualquer conhecimento que possa compartilhar! Um abraço!

Comment: Clique na setinha para cima, quando concordar com a resposta.

Comment: Clicado! Valeu pela ajuda! Comentei na resposta do cigano, se tiver alguma consideração, por favor! Abraço!

Comment: Não consigo comentar lá na sua publicação, me exige 50 pontos, mas, acho que um campo boolean não é elegante, para definição de Tipo de Pessoa,         public Tipos.TipoPessoa tipo { get; set; } ,

        public enum TipoPessoa : byte
        {
            Fisica = 1,
            Juridica = 2
        }