# Herança X Composição - MySQL C# Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, herança, composição

Estava com uma dúvida de modelagem de herança no C# envolvendo as entidades Pessoa, PessoaFísica e PessoaJurídica, mas Cigano Morrison Mendez ajudou bastante! Agora estou com outra dúvida em outro tipo de relacionamento. Como comentei, uma pessoa pode ser física ou jurídica. Uma pessoa ainda pode ser cliente e/ou fornecedor. E o cliente pode ter serviços relacionados. Segue a modelagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os modelos no código ficaram:

```
[Table("pessoa")]
public class pessoa
{

    [Key]
    public int idPessoa { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(90)]
    public string nomeRazaoSocial { get; set; }

    public virtual fornecedor fornecedor { get; set; }

    public virtual cliente cliente { get; set; }


}

[Table("pessoafisica")]
public class pessoafisica : pessoa
{

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string cpf { get; set; }

}

[Table("pessoajuridica")]
public class pessoajuridica : pessoa
{
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string cnpj { get; set; }

}

[Table("cliente")]
public class cliente
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("pessoa")]
    public int idPessoa { get; set; }

    public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }

}

[Table("fornecedor")]
public class fornecedor
{

    [Key, ForeignKey("pessoa")]
    public int idPessoa { get; set; }

    public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

Até aí tudo funcionou bem... a interação com o banco para cadastro, edição e consulta está ótimo. Porém, na hora de cadastrar os serviços estou com uma pulga atrás da orelha. Conceitualmente falando. Eu relacionei o serviço ao cliente e minha classe ficou:

```
[Table("servico")]
public class servico
{
    [Key]
    public int idServico { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("cliente")]
    public int idCliente { get; set; }

    public string descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual cliente cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Claramente uma PessoaFisica é uma classe herdada de Pessoa, assim como PessoaJuridica é uma classe herdada de Pessoa. Logo, seu eu tivesse uma tabela para os endereços das pessoas, na tabela de endereços eu usaria a chave da tabela Pessoa para manter o relacionamento. Uma pessoa sempre será OU pessoafisica OU pessoajuridica.

Agora tem outra questão... do Fornecedor e Cliente. Uma pessoa PODE OU NÃO ser um fornecedor... também PODE OU NÃO ser um cliente. E pode ser as duas coisas ou não ser nenhuma delas.

Embora um cliente ou fornecedor SEMPRE sejam uma pessoa, a entidade Serviço só poderá estar associada a um Cliente e nunca a um fornecedor (pelo menos nesta aplicação).

Aí vem a primeira dúvida... para esse conceito desejado, essa modelagem está correta? As chaves nas tabelas, cardinalidade... isso está certo?

Segunda dúvida...

Entendo que na tabela Serviço a chave de relacionamento idCliente deva conter a chave primária da tabela Cliente, e não a chave primária da tabela Pessoa. **ESSE CONCEITO ESTÁ CORRETO?**

Seguindo a valiosa ajuda do Cigano, montei estas classes e na controller de cadastro de serviço o preenchimento da lista de cliente ficou assim:

```
ViewBag.idCliente = new SelectList(db.cliente
                                            .Include(c => c.pessoa)
                                            .Select (c => new
                                            {
                                                idCliente = c.idPessoa,
                                                nomeRazaoSocial = c.pessoa.nomeRazaoSocial
                                            }).ToList(), "idCliente", "nomeRazaoSocial");
```

A aplicação funciona, porém ao se cadastrar no banco de dados, o campo idCliente da tabela serviço recebe o campo idPessoa da tabela pessoa. E isso está me deixando incomodado...

O campo idCliente da tabela serviço não deveria ter o campo idCliente, que é chave primária da tabela Cliente? Se sim, como devo ajustar minhas classes para que isso funcione?

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!

Comment: Tá esquisito isso aí. Como está a *View*?

Comment: Coloquei a view, Cigano!  Acho que a classe servico que tem alguma coisa. Quando segui sua sugestão, na classe cliente não tinha o atributo idCliente. Apenas o idPessoa com a notação [Key, ForeignKey("pessoa")]. Mas para fazer o o relacionamento de cliente 1 : n servico preciso ter o idCliente no servico, correto? Mas se não tem o idCliente na classe cliente, não funciona... estes mapeamentos estão corretos? Obrigado pela força!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valeu pela força, Cigano!

A modelagem tinha um problema. Essencialmente, a tabela cliente deveria ter como chave primária E chave estrangeira o campo idpessoa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Antes ela tinha idcliente como chave primária e idpessoa como chave estrangeira. Com isso, o banco sofria uma violação ao colocar o idpessoa na tabela servico.

As classes ficaram como o cigano falou:

```
[Table("final.pessoa")]
public class pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int idpessoa { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string nome { get; set; }

    public virtual cliente cliente { get; set; }

}

[Table("final.pessoafisica")]
public class pessoafisica : pessoa
{

    [StringLength(45)]
    public string cpf { get; set; }

}

[Table("final.pessoajuridica")]
public class pessoajuridica : pessoa
{

    [StringLength(45)]
    public string cnpj { get; set; }

}

[Table("final.cliente")]
public class cliente
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("pessoa")]
    public int idpessoa { get; set; }

    [StringLength(45)]
    public string codigo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<servico> servico { get; set; }

    public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }
}

[Table("final.servico")]
public class servico
{
    [Key]
    public int idservico { get; set; }

    public int idpessoa { get; set; }

    [StringLength(45)]
    public string descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual cliente cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Em resumo: em um relacionamento de cardinalidade 0...1, como no caso do cliente com pessoa, use como chave primária E chave estrangeira da tabela dependente o id da entidade principal.

Comment: Agora sim. Perfeito

Answer (score 1):

Sua composição está incorreta. `Cliente` tem relação 0 pra 1 ou 1 pra 1 com `Pessoa`. [Como eu disse na resposta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117306/modelagem-de-heran%C3%A7a-mysql-e-c?lq=1), o correto seria você fazer:

```
[Table("cliente")]
public class cliente
{
    // Cliente não deve ter Id própria. Apenas idPessoa.
    // [Key]
    // public int idCliente {get; set;}

    [Key, ForeignKey("pessoa")]
    public int idPessoa { get; set; }

    public int idCliente_Grupo { get; set; }

    public virtual cliente_grupo cliente_grupo { get; set; }

    public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<servico> servico { get; set; }
}
```

O mesmo vale para `Fornecedor`.

Apenas como adendo, eu não usaria Linq pra montar a consulta porque o suporte a carga preguiçosa/antecipada do Linq é limitado. Eu faria assim:

```
ViewBag.idCliente = new SelectList(db.Clientes
                                     .Include(c => c.Pessoa)
                                     .Select(c => new
                                      {
                                          idCliente = c.idPessoa,
                                          nomeRazaoSocial = c.Pessoa.nomeRazaoSocial
                                      }).ToList(), "idCliente", "nomeRazaoSocial");
```

---

> Essa modelagem está correta? As chaves nas tabelas, cardinalidade... isso está certo?

Com as suas modificações, sim. Perfeita, eu diria.

> Entendo que na tabela `Servico` a chave de relacionamento `idCliente` deva conter a chave primária da tabela `Cliente`, e não a chave primária da tabela `Pessoa`. ESSE CONCEITO ESTÁ CORRETO?

Sim, mas como a chave de `Cliente` é a chave de `Pessoa` (porque `Cliente` é, por composição, uma especialização de `Pessoa`), dá no mesmo.

Se você quiser manter o nome `idCliente` na modelagem, sem problemas. Até é melhor porque você explica por nomenclatura como `Servico` se relaciona com `Cliente`.

> O campo `idCliente` da tabela `Servico` não deveria ter o campo `idCliente`, que é chave primária da tabela `Cliente`?

Não. `idCliente` conceitualmente é equivalente a `idPessoa`, justamente porque `Cliente` é a especialização de `Pessoa`, por composição. Portanto, está correto montar a `SelectList` com o `idPessoa` porque a seleção dos dados parte de `Cliente`, e não de `Pessoa`, já verificando, assim, se `Pessoa` é um `Cliente` ou não.

Comment: Oi Cigano! Obrigado pela ajuda! A cardinalidade é de Pessoa 0 : 1 Cliente. Ou seja, um cliente é sempre uma pessoa. Mas nem sempre a pessoa é um cliente. Eu só coloquei o id no cliente porque a entidade servico tem que ser relacionada ao cliente. Um cliente pode ter 0 ou n serviços. Então minha dúvida era como modelar a classe serviço. Essa sua sugestão para ViewBag.idCliente que você deu não está funcionando porque a entidade cliente não tem o atributo idCliente... por isso eu havia tentado colocar...

Comment: É mesmo. Tem um erro na resposta. No mais, sobre isto: *"Ou seja, um cliente é sempre uma pessoa. Mas nem sempre a pessoa é um cliente. "*, a resposta atende perfeitamente. Veja agora, depois da edição.

Comment: Assim funciona, cigano... mas pelo que entendo a tabela serviço deveria guardar como chave estrangeira o id do cliente e não o id da pessoa. O modelo relacional funciona assim, não? Eu melhorei a pergunta... o que eu perguntei faz sentido? Como eu resolvo minha classe? Mais uma vez, obrigado!

Comment: Não, porque a única maneira de garantir que `Pessoa` tenha apenas um registro relacionado com `Cliente` é fazendo a chave primária de `Cliente` ser também chave estrangeira com `Pessoa`. Vou melhorar a resposta respondendo suas perguntas.

Comment: Mas aí dá problema no banco de dados. No modelo do BD, a tabela servico tem o campo idCliente como chave estrangeira para a tabela cliente. Quando se tenta colocar neste campo um valor do id da pessoa gera o erro de chave estrangeira inexistente. Ex: uma pessoa tem idPessoa 2. Na tabela cliente, ela tem o respectivo campo idPessoa = 2 mas tem o campo idCliente = 1 (chave prim). Quando o sistema tenta cadastrar na tabela servico o valor 2 no campo idCliente, não existe o valor 2 na tabela Cliente, gerando um erro de violação de chave estrangeira. Por isso tem algo errado no BD ou na classe.

Comment: Vou falar mais uma vez: `idCliente` e `idPessoa` **precisam ser a mesma coisa, senão não funciona**. Se uma `Pessoa` é `Cliente` e os respectivos Ids são diferentes, **está errada sua modelagem**. Entendido?

Comment: Valeu pela paciência, cigano... a modelagem não estava perfeita, agora consegui encontrar a inconsistência.