# LINQ to SQL com entidades que já existem, herança e composição

Tags: c#, herança, classes-abstratas, linq-to-sql, composição

Estou começando a estudar o LINQ para tentar implementar em um projeto que estou trabalhando.
Pelos exemplos tando em artigos como em vídeos, o LINQ tem uma interface no visual Studio que gera as classes de entidade a partir das tabelas no banco. Porém, no meu projeto de aplicação existem algumas particularidades.

1) Minhas classes de entidade já estão criadas, portanto quero poder usa-las com o LINQ.

2) A modelagem do meu banco funciona da seguinte forma. Tenho uma tabela chamada `Clientes` que é o que eu chamo de "Tabela filha" de outra tabela chamada `Pessoas`. Explicando, a tabela `Pessoas` faz o papel de uma tabela pai, que armazena parte dos dados de outras tabelas como `Clientes`, `Funcionarios`, etc. Ou seja, campos que são em comum nessas tabelas como (Nome, Email, Telefone, etc..) ficam todos armazenadas na tabela principal `Pessoas`. Seguindo o conceito de herança da OOP.
Na modelagem de classes que eu fiz, `Pessoa` é uma classe abstrata, ou seja, ela não pode existir sozinha, é apenas para servir de classe base para as classes concretas `Cliente` e `Funcionario`. Assim, quando um `Cliente` for inserido no banco parte dos dados deve ser gravado na tabela `Pessoas` e a outra parte na tabela de `Clientes`
Como o LINQ vai lidar com isso? Pois se eu fosse gerar as classes a partir das tabelas, o LINQ criaria uma classe concreta para a tabela `Pessoas` mas na minha modelagem UML `Pessoa` é uma classe abstrata.

Comment: O Linq não cria o domínio. Quem realiza isso é o Entity Framework. Sua pergunta irá contemplar o Entity Framework?

Comment: [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeY6B0Yk5zE&t=17m06s](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeY6B0Yk5zE&t=17m06s)

Comment: Acho que essa abordagem não cria a herança. O Entity Framework tem um dispositivo mais sofisticado para lidar com isso. Gostaria de saber como funciona? Ou quer uma resposta usando esta abordagem mesmo?

Comment: Sim, sempre é bem vindo outras alternativas

Comment: Como a pergunta inicial é baseada em `LINQ` deixo aqui um [artigo](https://ferhenriquef.com/2011/07/04/linq-to-sql-atributos-de-mapeamento-objeto-relacional/) que responde parte da pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, o mapeamento de herança em LINQ to SQL pode ser feito [conforme este tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399352(v=vs.100).aspx). É preciso definir uma coluna como *discriminator* na tabela pai. Esta tabela pai terá todos os campos da entidade pai e também das entidades derivadas, sendo os campos das entidades derivadas todos opcionais de serem preenchidos. O tratamento da validação do preenchimento destes campos é feito pela aplicação.

Herança e composição são clássicos da modelagem de dados, e a Microsoft desenvolveu um outro framework chamado Entity Framework que resolve muito bem estes casos. Exemplifico como fazer nas respostas abaixo:

- [Modelagem de herança MySQL e C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117306/modelagem-de-heran%C3%A7a-mysql-e-c/117311#117311)
- [Sugestão Migração Sistema e modelagem de pessoas físicas e jurídicas em sistema com Entity Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117219/sugest%C3%A3o-migra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-sistema/117243#117243)

Comment: Ainda sobre uma opção via LINQ, encontrei [isso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924682/using-linq-with-existing-objects). Só que não entendi muito bem.
Essas propriedades que o autor da resposta usa no exemplo já estão prontas no LINQ?

Comment: Ele usa exatamente como o Entity Framework funciona, usando um contexto de dados (que é uma implementação de uma Unit of Work) e chamando um `DbSet` que realiza as operações de seleção ou de persistência. Acho que vale muito a pena você ir atrás dos tutoriais de Entity Framework porque sua solução já está se direcionando para o uso dele.

Comment: Esses decoradores `[Table(Name = "AnyName")]`, `[Column]`, `[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]`, etc. Fazem parte do LINQ ou foram criados pelo autor?

Comment: Estive lendo o tutorial que você postou sobre sobre como usar herança com LINQ. Porém, na minha modelagem, a classe base é abstrata. Isso será um problema para implementar a solução descrita no tutorial?

Comment: Sobre os decoradores, eles fazem parte do framework .NET. Não apenas do LINQ. Sobre a segunda, acredito que não.