# Mapeamento relacionamento Muitos-Para-Muitos - EF Core - C#

Tags: c#

Já tentei mapear um relacionamento entre 3 classes, mas estou apanhando. Tenho uma classe Pessoa que representa uma Pessoa qualquer, um Funcionário, um Cliente, um Fornecedor, enfim, qualquer tipo de Pessoa, seja ela física ou jurídica... Quando eu for cadastrar um determinado tipo de pessoa, precisarei usar a tabela PessoaCadastro para poder guardar dados mais específicos de cada pessoa... Notem que muitos campos fazem relacionamento com o campo PessoaId da tblPessoa (exceto o campo Id, pois ele será apenas um campo PK e não se relaciona com nenhum campo), mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que as chaves estrangeiras fiquem certas... O resultado que obtive foi isso:

[image: Resultado que obtive]

O que preciso mudar em minhas classes e no mapeamento?

No banco de dados preciso que as tabelas fiquem assim:

[image: Preciso que as tabelas fiquem assim]

```js
public class Pessoa
    {
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }
        public int PessoaTipoId { get; set; }

        public virtual PessoaTipo PessoaTipo { get; set; }
        public virtual PessoaFisica PessoaFisica { get; set; }
        public virtual PessoaJuridica PessoaJuridica { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PessoaCadastro> PessoasCadastros { get; set; }

    }
```

```js
public class PessoaCadTipo
    {
        public int PessoaCadTipoId { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public bool Sistema { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataInclusao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PessoaCadastro> PessoasCadastros { get; set; }
    }
```

```js
public class PessoaCadastro
    {
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }
        public int PessoaCadTipoId { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PessoaFilialId { get; set; }
        public int PessoaFilialCadId { get; set; }
        public int PessoaFuncCadId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataInclusao { get; set; }
        public bool Sistema { get; set; }

        public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
        public virtual PessoaCadTipo PessoaCadTipo { get; set; }

    }
```

```js
//Mapeamento da Classe PessoaCadastro
public void PessoaCadastroMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaCadastro>()
                .ToTable("tblPessoaCadastro");

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaCadastro>()
                .HasKey(p => new {p.PessoaId, p.PessoaCadTipoId, p.Id, p.PessoaFilialId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaCadastro>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Pessoa)
                .WithMany(p => p.PessoasCadastros)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.PessoaId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Pessoa_PessoaCad")
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaCadastro>()
                .HasOne(p => p.PessoaCadTipo)
                .WithMany(p => p.PessoasCadastros)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.PessoaCadTipoId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_PessoaCadTipo_PessoaCad")
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaCadastro>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Pessoa)
                .WithMany(p => p.PessoasCadastros)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.PessoaFilialId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_PessoaFilial_PessoaCad")
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaCadastro>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Pessoa)
                .WithMany(p => p.PessoasCadastros)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.PessoaFilialCadId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_PessoaFilialCad_PessoaCad")
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaCadastro>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Pessoa)
                .WithMany(p => p.PessoasCadastros)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.PessoaFuncCadId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_PessoaFuncCad_PessoaCad")
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaCadastro>()
                .Property(p => p.Sistema)
                .HasColumnName("Sistema")
                .HasColumnType("Bit");

            modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaCadastro>()
                .Property(p => p.DataInclusao)
                .HasColumnName("DataInclusao")
                .HasColumnType("DateTime")
                .IsRequired();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não precisa complicar tanto. Vamos primeiro à uma análise sobre seu caso:

> Tenho uma classe Pessoa que representa uma Pessoa qualquer, um Funcionário, um Cliente, um Fornecedor, enfim, qualquer tipo de Pessoa, seja ela física ou jurídica.

A meu ver, uma pessoa só pode ser ou física ou jurídica, mas pode também ser um cliente, um fornecedor, ambos ou nenhum.

Ou seja, `Pessoa`, `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica` são casos de herança, [conforme explico aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117219/sugest%C3%A3o-migra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-sistema-e-modelagem-de-pessoas-f%C3%ADsicas-e-jur%C3%ADdicas-em-sistema/117243#117243). `Cliente` e `Fornecedor` são casos de composição, [conforme explico aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117306/modelagem-de-heran%C3%A7a-mysql-e-c/117311#117311).

> Quando eu for cadastrar um determinado tipo de pessoa, precisarei usar a tabela PessoaCadastro para poder guardar dados mais específicos de cada pessoa.

Não precisa não. Veja as respostas.

> O que preciso mudar em minhas classes e no mapeamento?

Bom, junte as duas respostas e você obterá o que procura. Livre-se da Fluent API também. Você não precisa dela.

Comment: Li suas respostas sobre herança e composição, muito bom. Uma pergunta: Há problemas em fazer apenas um cadastro de pessoas, tanto para física ou jurídica?

Comment: Problemas, não. Depende do objetivo. Eu tenho um curso em que discuto as estratégias de herança e composição com o aluno, além de usar tabela unificada ou não. Gostaria de saber mais?

Comment: Já estou ciente dos cursos que você ministra por Hangouts, mas no momento não posso, estou fazendo um de ASP.NET MVC, em seguida já tenho um de Entity. Obrigado e parabéns pelas suas respostas! =]