# Como e onde implementar as regras de negócio no Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Possuo o seguinte exemplo de um software que utiliza o *Entity Framework*, que acessa um banco de dados com apenas uma tabela chamada `Produtos` com os seguintes campos:

- Campo `int produtoid`.
- Campo `string nomeproduto`.
- Campo `int categoriaid`.

Ele também possui um formulário onde eu realizo o **CRUD**, veja:

[image: formulario]

Aqui segue o código dos dois arquivos gerados pelo EF que é o meu *Context* e a minha classe `Produtos`.

Classe `Produtos`:

```
namespace CRUD_EF
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Produtos
    {
        public int produtoid { get; set; }
        public string nomeproduto { get; set; }
        public int categoriaid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Classe `ExemploEFEntities`:

```
namespace CRUD_EF
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class ExemploEFEntities : DbContext
    {
        public ExemploEFEntities()
            : base("name=ExemploEFEntities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Produtos> Produtos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

E este é todo o código do meu formulário (Form1.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CRUD_EF
{
    public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
    {
        public frmPrincipal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lerProdutos();
        }

        private void lerProdutos() 
        {
            ExemploEFEntities context = new ExemploEFEntities();

            IEnumerable<Produtos> produtos = from p 
                                             in context.Produtos 
                                             select p;

            dataGridViewProdutos.DataSource = produtos.ToList();
        }

        private void incluir(string nomeProduto, int idCategoria) 
        {
            ExemploEFEntities context = new ExemploEFEntities();
            
            Produtos novoProduto = new Produtos()
            {
                nomeproduto = nomeProduto,
                categoriaid = idCategoria
            };

            context.Produtos.Add(novoProduto);
            context.SaveChanges();

            lerProdutos();
        }

        private void btnIncluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            incluir(txtNome.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtCategoriaID.Text));
        }

        private void btnAlterar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            alterar();
        }

        private void alterar() 
        {
            ExemploEFEntities context = new ExemploEFEntities();

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtProdutoId.Text);

            Produtos produto = context.Produtos.First(p => p.produtoid == id);
            produto.nomeproduto = txtNome.Text;
            produto.categoriaid = Convert.ToInt32(txtCategoriaID.Text);                        

            context.SaveChanges();

            lerProdutos();
        }

        private void deletar() 
        {
            ExemploEFEntities context = new ExemploEFEntities();
            
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtProdutoId.Text);

            Produtos produto = context.Produtos.First(p => p.produtoid == id);

            context.Produtos.Remove(produto);
            context.SaveChanges();

            lerProdutos();
        }

        private void btnExcluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            deletar();
        }

        private void query(int id) 
        {
            ExemploEFEntities context = new ExemploEFEntities();

            Produtos produto = context.Produtos.First(p => p.produtoid == id);

            txtProdutoId.Text = produto.produtoid.ToString();
            txtNome.Text = produto.nomeproduto.ToString();
            txtCategoriaID.Text = produto.categoriaid.ToString();
        }

        private void dataGridViewProdutos_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try 
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewProdutos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
                
                query(id);
            }
            catch 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Houve um erro!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Minha dúvida.

Levando em conta toda a estrutura acima gerada pelo *Entity Framework* eu gostaria de saber como e onde eu poderia implementar as regras de negócio?

Para facilitar e ilustrar a situação vamos considerar a seguinte regra:

> Não é permitido cadastrar produtos com o nome exatamente igual.

Como e onde eu implementaria esta regra?

Comment: drmcarvalho, cuidado ao declarar o seu contexto fora de um bloco `using`, isto vai gerar um desperdício de recursos, então sempre faça como nos exemplos do @ismael.

Comment: Quanto a adicionar as restrições, você não precisa usar `Repository Patterns` , apenas faça uso de `Data Annotations` e/ou regras no `Mapeamento`, coisas como tamanho do registro, conjuntos de registros unicos, restriçoes (valor unico, intervalo, maior que outro campo, etc), relacionamentos são facilmente configurados usando `DataAnnotations` ou no Mapeamento.

Comment: A sim, como eu poderia usar os Annotations? Vc poderia publicar uma resposta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sua pergunta é um pouco complexa em termos de implementação. Regras de negócio não é um assunto fácil de ser discutido. Existe [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114084/20615) onde é explicado um pouco sobre isso.

Mas, tentando responder um pouco, você pode fazer de algumas formas. Eu aconselho duas formas. Uma é utilizando o [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj129537.aspx), como o [@TobyMosque comenta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129595/como-e-onde-implementar-as-regras-de-neg%C3%B3cio-no-entity-framework#comment269915_129595) e a outra forma sera utilizando o [`IValidableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

Não aconselho criar um método apenas para isso, pois o *framework* e a linguagem que você está utilizando oferecem alternativas melhores.

Usando **DataAnnotations**, você precisaria criar um novo atributo. [Esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2691444/4843158) possui um exemplo de como implementar.

Caso queira utilizar `IValidableObject`, pode ver um exemplo [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3400542/4843158).

Comment: Olhando pela tecnologia utilizada na pergunta, a resposta do @ismael é interessante, mas não aconselharia usar o banco para isso. Você possui muitas formas de fazer isso sem criar gatilhos no banco.

Comment: Se eu colocar todas as formas e exemplos aqui, a resposta ficaria extensa demais, e creio que você não iria conseguir entender muito bem os conceitos. Caso queira mais informações, abra perguntas sobre as dúvidas, que será melhor.

Answer (score 4):

Por exemplo, antes de inserir ou alterar seu registro, você poderia chamar um método (booleano) com as regras necessárias.

As regras poderiam ser definidas no próprio banco de dados através de *triggers* ou mesmo *stored procedures* que seriam chamadas pela aplicação (existem vários prós nesse tipo de implementação).

Focando apenas no problema proposto, veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
private void incluir(string nomeProduto, int idCategoria) 
{
    if (RegistroValido(nomeProduto, idCategoria))
    {
        using (ExemploEFEntities context = new ExemploEFEntities())
        {
            Produtos novoProduto = new Produtos()
            {
                nomeproduto = nomeProduto,
                categoriaid = idCategoria
            };

            context.Produtos.Add(novoProduto);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        lerProdutos();
    }
}


private bool RegistroValido(string nomeProduto, int idCategoria)
{
    bool retValido = false;
    int erro = 0;
    using (ExemploEFEntities context = new ExemploEFEntities())
    {
        //busca na tabela de produtos um com o mesmo nome
        if (context.Produtos.Count(x => x.nomeproduto.ToUpper().Equals(nomeProduto.ToUpper())) > 0)
            erro = 1;

        if (idCategoria == 0)
            erro = 2;
    }

    swicth (erro)
    {
        case 1:
            MessageBox.Show("Não é permitido cadastrar produtos com o nome exatamente igual.","Atenção!");
            break;
        case 2:
            MessageBox.Show("Não é permitido cadastrar um produto sem categoria.","Atenção!");
            break;
        default:
            retValido = true;
            break;
    }

    return retValido;
}
```

Esse é um dos cenários possíveis.

Comment: Esta forma tem vários problemas. A etapa de validação deve ser feita na chamada de `ModelState.IsValid`. Neste momento ocorrem dois eventos no ciclo da requisição: o primeiro é a validação por atributos ([aqui tem um exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117219/sugest%C3%A3o-migra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-sistema/117243#117243)), e o segundo ocorre se o *Model* implementa `IValidatableObject`. O primeiro pode usar o contexto de dados. O segundo é uma validação apenas dentro do próprio *Model*, entre seus campos.

Comment: Por fim, [aqui tem um exemplo de como chamar um contexto de validação em Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29327343/1314276), na falta de um `ModelState`.

Answer (score 0):

Você teria então várias camadas, por exemplo:

- ProdutosDAO
- ProdutosRN
- ProdutosForm (não gosto de usar controller aqui, gosto meu).

**ProdutosDAO** teria todos os métodos de CRUD no banco de dados.

**ProdutosRN** você instancia ProdutosDAO e no método de salvar você pode consultar se já não existe um Produto com mesmo nome, caso positivo lança uma Exception (que seria tratada no form).

**ProdutosForm** você instancia ProdutosRN para chamar os métodos da regra de negócio e trata da parte visual.